# SQL query to get student enrolled in this month in a course - Moodle

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to get the total students who have enrolled in a particular course, with a course id, in this month only. The table structure is same as what remains in most of the Moodle databases.

I dont want the total of students of all time, I just want to get them in this month.

The code can be something related to those provided on this page: [SQL query for Courses Enrolment on Moodle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161606/sql-query-for-courses-enrolment-on-moodle)

The above link provides similar codes but does not include the **date** part which I want.

You can suggest me any other way also like using external webservices on moodle if this function exists there.

Comment: Hi - all questions on this forum need to be self-contained. Please update your question with the source table structures, sample data, the result you want to achieve and the SQL you’ve managed to write yourself - all as editable text, appropriately formatted